# gmpy2 unexpected behavior of pow() method on mpfr type

Tags: python, mpfr

I have reproducibly found that using gmpy2's pow function on its mpfr type returns 0 on any x value <= .5

```
>>> from gmpy2 import mpfr
>>> x = mpfr('.5')
>>> y = mpfr('2')
>>> print(pow(x, 2))
0.0 -> should be .25
>>> print(pow(y, 2))
4.0 -> correct
```

am I using the wrong function, or is there something that I am not getting here

Comment: gmpy2 maintainer here. You found a bug. I'll add an answer with an update later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You found a bug that was missed in the test suite. I recently added an optimization for mpfr(<<some small numbers>>) ** <<small Python integer>>. I have identified the cause and am validating the fix.

A work-around is to convert the exponent to an mpz first.

I have pushed out a new release. Please test version 2.1.0rc2. It can be installed with the command:

pip install gmpy2==2.1.0rc2

Comment: thank you, this is a first for me actually finding a new bug, and it not being my fault lol